# Typescript-Compile: "Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token "]" at compile"

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, syntax-error

My website for testing gives me an error when I try to load my webpage. I'm using TypeScript-Compile to compile it and it gives me an error with no explanation, and points to code in the typescript-compile source code.

http://hazelpy.ml/ is the website if you want to check the logs.

Here is the HTML source:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TypeScript</title>

    <style media="screen">
      #GameCanvas {
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 1px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="GameCanvas" width="1080" height="720"></canvas>

    <script type="text/typescript" charset="utf-8">
      const CVS = document.getElementById("GameCanvas");
      const CTX = CVS.getContext("2d");

      class GameObject {
        position;
        color: string;
        width: number;
        height: number;

        constructor (position, color, width, height) {
          this.position = position;
          this.color = color;
          this.width = width;
          this.height = height;
        }

        fill(Context) {
          Context.save();

          Context.fillStyle = this.color;
          Context.fill(this.position[0], this.position[1], this.width, this.height);

          Context.restore();
        }
      }

      function EndGame() {
        return false;
      }

      var GameRunning: boolean = true;

      const objects: GameObject[] = [];
      objects.push(new GameObject([0, 0], "rgb(255, 255, 0)", 10, 10));

      while (GameRunning) {
        CTX.clearRect(0, 0, 1080, 720);

        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
          var Selected: GameObject = objects[i];

          Selected.fill(CTX);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="./source/typescript.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./source/typescript.compile.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Yes, I have tried moving the two typescript compile scripts to before the  tag. Did nothing.

The problem seems to be in the typescript-compile min file on the third to last line. I wouldn't be able to tell where the problem is though.

Comment: the online validator I put it through wanted those scripts inside the /body and also <script type="text/typescript" charset="utf-8"> caused "Element “script” must not have attribute “charset” unless attribute “src” is also specified." so perhaps try     <script type="text/typescript" > there

Comment: @JeremyKahan I tried removing the charset attribute, no effect.

Comment: thanks for trying. I hope someone out there has a better idea

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was in my code where I said:

```js
const objects: GameObject[] = [];
```

I hadn't noticed at the moment that using `const` in this scenario was not the right choice. Changing this to a var fixed the issue.